# 405 Method Not Allowed despite CORS

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, cors, angular-httpclient

I am trying to develop a frontend application using Angular. Since I added the **authorization header** to the HTTP POST and GET requests, I'm getting **405 Method Not Allowed**, although I seemingly allow everything on the server side.

[image]

The debugger in my browser Chrome says it's asking for `Access-Control-Request-Method: POST` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization`, my backend allows both, `access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST` and `access-control-allow-headers: authorization`, as well as `access-control-allow-credentials: true`.

I don't see what I'm missing here. The server is a node.js express server, the headers are set like this:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'authorization');
```

The frontend code (Angular 5) looks like this:

```
this.http.request('post', apiUrl, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer abc'),
}).subscribe(response => {
  // some code
});
```

Where `this.http` is an instance of Angular's `HttpClient`.

My frontend application is served from my localhost domain "http://frontend.localhost/app", my backend server is located at "http://backend.localhost".

My question is, am I missing some headers I have to set on my backend? Do I need to set some options in my frontend application?

Comment: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');`,  add 'OPTIONS' as well.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev I added 'OPTIONS' to the allowed methods, but the error message keeps the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out my issue is *not* directly related to CORS. My backend is currently a GraphQL server only, which allows GET and POST requests.

If I add additional headers on the client side, the browser is checking for CORS via a preflight *OPTIONS* request, to the URL where the GraphQL server resides. This results in a *405 Method Not Allowed* **error produced by the GraphQL server**, not by Express or the browser.

Comment: Simon, on a side-note, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` IS NOT allowed with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. If you're going to pass credentials (authorization header and/or cookies), you MUST specify a specific origin in the ACAO header - easiest to implement as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {value of Origin request header}`.