# HTTP status code 405 error when adding headers to request

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, http-headers, axios

I have a problem making get requests to a server when headers are being set with the Axios/http request. Any header I add (except the `content-type` header) causes the same error: "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405." This is true in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc.

Specifically, I need to add the Authorization header for account validation for a service I need to connect with.

Running a GET request on Postman using the API URI works fine and I get the required response. Running this in my React application in the browser gives me the HTTP 405 error. I'm running this on a local Node server with Google's `Allow-Control-Origin` extension installed and enabled using `http://localhost:3000`.

When I run the request without any header parameters:

`axios.get("https://myrequest.com/req/reqservice.svc/Login",).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err))`

The request works fine. When I run it with headers (any header, but in my case, the Authorization header), I get the error:

`axios.get("https://myrequest.com/req/reqservice.svc/Login", { headers: { "Authorization": "randomExample" } }).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err))`

So, what could be causing the issue? If it was a CORS or connection issue, wouldn't I have trouble making a request in general? I've been perusing Stack Overflow forever with no answer giving me the solution. I'm totally lost at what to do and I've been working on it for days already without a single solution. Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139612/405-method-not-allowed-despite-cors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [405 Method Not Allowed despite CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139612/405-method-not-allowed-despite-cors)

Comment: @tanaydin That question offers no solution to the problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: 405 - Method not allowed ... your server probably doesn't allow `OPTIONS` method - what is this "Google's allow-control-origin extension"?

Comment: @JaromandaX It's just a Chrome browser plugin that allows localhost communication between browser and server without causing CORS issues on localhost server.

Comment: oh right, and you expect this to help Edge and Firefox as well?

Comment: @JaromandaX No, only Google. But the problem happens with any browser so it doesn't really matter to be honest.

Comment: adding headers triggers pre-flight ... pre-flight means a `OPTIONS` request before the `GET` request ... if your server doesn't "understand" or "handle" `OPTIONS` request, you'll get a `405 Method not allowed` error - so, you need to handle OPTIONS requests on your **server**

Comment: It may be a good idea to show us your source code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is due to CORS. You need to specify the correct value for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` server side for the preflight (OPTIONS) request ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers))

[More details about CORS in general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Modify your server to add the missing header(s). From your question, you need to at least add `Authorization` value.

**node js server**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
//...
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
```

About **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**

> The Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header is used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used during the actual request.

So, in your server side response, when setting `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, you need to specify a list of **comma-separated** headers.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: <header-name>, <header-name>, ...
```

You only need to specify it for **custom** headers, as by default some headers are already accepted.

> The simple headers, Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type (but only with a MIME type of its parsed value (ignoring parameters) of either application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain), are always available and don't need to be listed by this header.

So in your case it works if you just specify `Content-type` because `Content-Type` is accepted by default (as explained just above)

**Note** If the value for `Content-type` is not of one of the types above (e.g. if you submit your authorization request as `application/json`), then you need to add it in the list (comma-separated)

**node js server**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
//...
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type');
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question so horribly ☹️

Comment: @MunimMunna the 405 error can also be what you said, but since it seems to be working with content-type I thought it could be just the headers

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it does not solve the issue. The issue is about allowing Authorization header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make all routes cors enabled add the following script to your `index.js`.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

If you want to make only a single route cors enabled you can enable it like this:

```
router.get('/corspage', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.send('cors problem fixed:)');
});
```

If you are OK with using additional package for that you can use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package to do it with lot less code. Install the package and add the following code to `index.js`.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
```

If you want to enable single route with **cors** package:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.get('/products/:id', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a Single Route'})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because this is a CORS call and you get a preflight request to which your server must respond accordingly:

You will get an `Origin: http://blah.com` header from the client.

There are several headers you should set when replying to preflight checks:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://blah.com` - sets the allowed origins * - for all origins, or domain name if one is needed

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` - Set whether or not cookies are allowed from this origin.

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS` - Actions allowed by this origin.

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` - What headers are allowed from this origin you may set custom headers here.

These preflight checks are OPTIONS calls not GET or POST so you can easily detect them and answer correctly. You may not answer content to the Options call but only set these mandatory headers so the client knows what the CORS policy for this connection is. After this has been done the client will issue the actual GET/POST request as you have issued it in the ajax calling the server.